# Python - tkinter remove space between scrollbar and entry widgets

Tags: python, widget, tkinter, scrollbar

In my program I have a `ttk.Scrollbar` which works in tandem with a read-only `ttk.Entry` widget. The problem I have is that there is a spacing between the bottom of the entry widget and the top of the scrollbar widget. I want to get rid of that but `tkinter` doesn't allow you to use negative padding and such.

For some reason, the scrollbar is the only widget that naturally places a `pady` attribute.

Below is the code, the scrollbar widget and the relative entry widget commented out.

```
from tkinter import *  
from tkinter import ttk 

def calculate(*args):   
    try:   
        value = int(binary.get(), 2)    
        decimal.set(value) 
    except ValueError:  
        error = "Please enter a binary value."
        decimal.set(error)
        pass    

root = Tk()     #set object `root` to `Tk()`
root.title("Binary to Decimal Converter")   
root.wm_iconbitmap("binaryicon.ico")    
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
root.resizable(False, False)

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding = "3 3 12 12")  
mainframe.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = (N, W, E, S))  
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1) 
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

binary = StringVar()    
decimal = StringVar()   

binary_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width = 32, textvariable = binary)
binary_entry.grid(column = 2, row = 1, sticky = (W, E))

"""decimalView = ttk.Entry(mainframe, state = "readonly", background = "gray99", width = 32, textvariable = decimal)
decimalView.grid(column = 2, row = 2, sticky = W)
scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(mainframe, orient = HORIZONTAL, command = decimalView.xview)
scrollbar.grid(column = 2, row = 3, sticky = (N, S, E, W))
decimalView.configure(xscrollcommand = scrollbar.set)"""
ttk.Button(mainframe, text = "Calculate", command = calculate).grid(column = 3, row = 3, sticky = W)

ttk.Label(mainframe, text = "Binary").grid(column = 3, row = 1, sticky = W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text = "Decimal").grid(column = 3, row = 2, sticky = W)

binary_entry.focus()
root.bind("<Return>", calculate)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific case, the simplest solution is to use `sticky=(N, E, W)`. Your code currently makes it sticky to both the top and bottom of the cell (both `N` and `S`), causing it to ether stretch or be centered in the cell (on the Mac, for instance, scrollbars are a fixed size, so they will be centered rather than stretched). Since you want it to "stick" to the bottom of the widget immediately above it, you don't want it to also "stick" to the bottom of its own cell.